# CLLocationManager didUpdateToLocation checking failing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get the location coordinates using CLLocationManager. Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //instantiate location manager and set delegate
    self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    // can be set to 100m,1km,3km etc.
    //locationManager.distanceFilter=10.0f;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    //start updating the delegate
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
      fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    // Check if the coordinates are different from the old ones
    if (newLocation.coordinate.latitude != oldLocation.coordinate.latitude && 
        newLocation.coordinate.longitude != oldLocation.coordinate.longitude) {     

        NSLog(@"not equal");        
    } else {
        NSLog(@"equal");
    }
}
```

However i find the condition is called twice. First time the condition is satisfied and prints **not equal** and immediately its called again and prints "equal". Can some1 help me out ? What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the condition itself being checked twice during the same method call?  Or, is the method itself being called twice?

Comment: I am not able to figure that out. But I am calling the [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] just once in my viewDidLoad

Comment: Can you just drop an `NSLog()` call before the condition to see if the delegate method itself is being called twice?

Comment: yes.the method itself is being called twice.

Comment: Try [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] in the if and else statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because CoreLocation cache your last location and return it immediately after you called **startUpdatingLocation** so you have to validate coordinate timestamp and it is too old, you can ignore old coordinate.

**UPDATE:**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    if([newLocation horizontalAccuracy] < 0.0f) return;
    if(fabs([[newLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow]) > kCLLocationMaximumLocationDataAge) return;
    if(fabs([[oldLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow]) < kCLLocationMaximumLocationDataAge && [newLocation getDistanceFrom:oldLocation] < 0.1f && [newLocation horizontalAccuracy] == [oldLocation horizontalAccuracy])
        return;
    if(((runningHighPreciseLocationDetectionService||runningLowPowerLocationDetectionService) && ([newLocation horizontalAccuracy] <= kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters))){
        NSLog(@"---> \n%@\n%@\nHorizontal accurecy: %f\nLocation age: %fs\nOld location age: %fs", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), newLocation, newLocation.horizontalAccuracy, fabs([[newLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow]), fabs([[oldLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow]));
    } else {
        NSLog(@"\n-------------- BAD ---------------\n%@\n%@\nHorizontal accurecy: %f\nLocation age: %fs\nOld location age: %fs\n----------------------------------", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), newLocation, newLocation.horizontalAccuracy, fabs([[newLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow]), fabs([[oldLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow]));
    }
    if(((runningHighPreciseLocationDetectionService||runningLowPowerLocationDetectionService) && ([newLocation horizontalAccuracy] <= kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters))){
        [self stopLocationImprovementTimer];
    } else [self createLocatinoImprovementTimer];
}
```

**createLocatinoImprovementTimer** method used to launch timer, which will work for certain amount of time and if it wasn't stopped it will send and update notification with location, which was last. This timer will help to wait for coordinate with better accuracy before notify controllers.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but still: `getDistanceFrom` is deprecated since iOS 3.2, so it should be `[newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation]`