# didUpdateToLocation called twice, ok. Why is oldLocation nil both times?

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I understand that CLLocationManager is called twice on init in most cases, [once with cached location data, and once with updated content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6980891/111243).

This makes sense, even when it returns the same result in both cases (eg: because simulated location always returns the same coord and accuracy).

Here is a log from my startup process. didUpdateToLocation called twice, both times oldLocation is nil:

```
// Setup code:
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

// Log Output:
locationManager didUpdateToLocation 
old: nil 
new: <+22.28468100,+114.15817700> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 6/25/15, 3:21:57 PM Indochina Time

locationManager didUpdateToLocation 
old: nil 
new: <+22.28468100,+114.15817700> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 6/25/15, 3:22:01 PM Indochina Time
```

What doesn't make sense is that `oldLocation` is always nil in these cases. I have to provide an external variable I call `actualOldLocation` to keep track of the change in distance between updates. Am I doing something wrong that causes this value to be nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What iOS are you targeting? didUpdateToLocation was deprecated from iOS 6.0, not sure that it works fully nowadays.

Comment: ...doh. That, uh, explains the wierdness. But seriously, an array of AnyObject? That's the improved version?

Comment: This explains why the old api doesn't return an oldLocation any more--locations.count is always 1: on first run, on 2nd non-cache update, and when I change the simulator location. I'm happy with this explanation.